# enabling https on GCF project

Tags: https, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a GCF project that mostly uses functions-framework. The project is based on TS and express without node. I need to turn on https on it but I cannot find any resources that clarify that. Can this be done? and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http). This will enable a function to run in response to an HTTP(S) request. The required endpoint will depend on your Cloud Function (1st gen or 2nd gen). 2nd gen always requires HTTPS, while in 1st gen you can choose if HTTPS is required. Take a look at [deployment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http#deployment).